# Usage of this* in make_unique

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, factory-pattern

I have a small example of a `Factory` design pattern, and I am interested in this part:

```
std::make_unique< A >(*this)
```

...especially `*this`.

Does it mean that the `clone()` method return a `std::unique_ptr` which points to member of factory class? 
And `createInstance()` always returns the same member of the `Factory` class?

I am just confused what `std::make_unique< A >(*this)` is supposed to do, because `A` has in constructor `std::string`, not a pointer to itself.

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() {}
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() = 0;
        virtual void print() = 0;
};

class A: public Base {
        std::string name_;
    public:
        A(std::string name ){name_ = name;};
        std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() override{
            return std::make_unique<A>(*this);
        };
        void print( ) override{
            std::cout << "Class A: " << name_;    
        };
        virtual ~A(){};
};

class Factory{
        std::unique_ptr<A> type = std::make_unique<A>("MyName");  
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<Base> createInstance(){
            return type->clone();
    }
};

int main(){
    Factory factory;
    auto instance = factory.createInstance();
    instance->print();
}
```

Comment: "_not a pointer to itself_" Did you miss the dereference operator in `*this`? ;)

Comment: "Usage of this* in make_unique" - I believe you mean `*this`, not `this*`. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::make_unique<A>(*this)` is basically equivalent to:

```
unique_ptr<A>(new A(*this))
```

In `clone()`, `*this` is an lvalue-reference to `A`, so you are constructing a `A` from an (lvalue-reference to) `A` (inside `std::make_unique`), so you are using the implicitly declared copy-constructor of `A`:

```
A(A const&);
```

So you are effectively making a copy of the current object into a newly allocate block of memory.

Since `createInstance` uses `clone()`, you are creating a "copy" of `type` each time you call `createInstance`.

Comment: @curiousguy There is no such thing as lvalue reference types in C++? If you want to be pedantic, maybe add details to your comments, I am not able to read mind yet.

Comment: @curiousguy Not what the standard says: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types / http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref If you do not consider references as type it means that you cannot declare variable that are references, are use reference types as template arguments.

Comment: "_do not consider references as type_" I wrote no such thing. A reference type is a type. `*this` is not a reference.

Comment: @curiousguy *"There is no reference types."* vs. *"A reference type is a type"*? Which one? The type of `*this` is exactly `A&`, you can test it on any compliant compiler, `decltype(*this)` is exactly `A&`. *"The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points."* (http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1)

Comment: Nope. Nothing is ever of type reference in C or in C++.

Comment: @curiousguy Three links to the standard mentioning reference types are not enough? Maybe you should point me to higher places indicating there are no references in C++? You wrote 4 comments, two of wish being in contradiction (*"There is no reference types"*, *"Nothing is ever of type reference"*, *"A reference type is as type"*), without anything to back up your saying. I am ending this conversation until you look at the three links I put in my previous comments.

Comment: And yet `*this` still is not a reference, and none of your irrelevant links says that anything "_of type A&_" in either C or C++

Comment: @curiousguy `decltype(*this)` is `A&` so `*this` is of type `A&`, much like `decltype(0)` is `int` so `0` is of type `int`. - Maybe you'd care to indicate what is the type of `*this` is your world?

Comment: `*p` has the same type in C or in C++, and it isn't a reference. It's T if p has type `T*`. Read any example in the std, it never says: `int i; (i); // has int& type`

Comment: "_Three links to the standard mentioning reference types are not enough?_" Do you read the text you link to?

Comment: @curiousguy Since I need to sleep, I've rephrased the sentence to *"`*this` is an lvalue-reference to A"*, hope you'll be satisfied with it.